# mesos-containerizer failed to load libmesos-1.0.1.so

Tags: mesos

I am trying to deploy a  tensorflow(with mesos container) on my DC/OS(v1.8.4) environment, the destination node has gpu resources and nvidia driver has been installed
 The tensorflow failed,  there is only one error message in mesos's stderr:

```
 mesos-containerizer: error while loading shared libraries: libmesos-1.0.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

in mesos log, there are below messages:

```
Jun 23 10:25:43 gpu-test linker-start-agent.sh[4198]: I0623 10:25:43.069501  4222 linux_launcher.cpp:281] Cloning child process with flags = CLONE_NEWNS | CLONE_NEWPID
Jun 23 10:25:43 gpu-test linker-start-agent.sh[4198]: I0623 10:25:43.072198  4222 systemd.cpp:96] Assigned child process '4977' to 'mesos_executors.slice'
Jun 23 10:25:43 gpu-test linker-start-agent.sh[4198]: I0623 10:25:43.074686  4222 containerizer.cpp:1319] Checkpointing executor's forked pid 4977 to '/var/lib/
mesos/slave/meta/slaves/e97f452e-17de-4c0e-b07d-b9955bbc0844-S3/frameworks/00da5f21-f3ab-4237-b85e-8b767ef53d43-0000/executors/gpu2-cuda.49c58356-57fe-11e7-afed-56b5da32b775/runs/f5ad3b1b-5beb-45d6-b4d4-bd592ae09be8/pids/forked.pid'
Jun 23 10:25:43 gpu-test linker-start-agent.sh[4198]: I0623 10:25:43.077404  4222 containerizer.cpp:1863] Executor for container 'f5ad3b1b-5beb-45d6-b4d4-bd592ae09be8' has exited
Jun 23 10:25:43 gpu-test linker-start-agent.sh[4198]: I0623 10:25:43.077416  4222 containerizer.cpp:1622] Destroying container 'f5ad3b1b-5beb-45d6-b4d4-bd592ae09be8'
Jun 23 10:25:43 gpu-test linker-start-agent.sh[4198]: E0623 10:25:43.178581  4219 slave.cpp:3976] Container 'f5ad3b1b-5beb-45d6-b4d4-bd592ae09be8' for executor'gpu2-cuda.49c58356-57fe-11e7-afed-56b5da32b775' of framework 00da5f21-f3ab-4237-b85e-8b767ef53d43-0000 failed to start: Collect failed: Failed to setup hostname and network files: Failed to enter the mount namespace of pid 4977: Pid 4977 does not exist
```

The logs shows it failed when forking pid process.
  But if I try to deploy a nginx service with mesos contianer,  it run very well, mesos-containerizer failed to load libmesos-1.0.1.so when deploy tensorflow or cuda service, but goes well for nginx service, there are all mesos containers

I don't know where goes wrong~

Comment: Does tensorflow re/set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ?

Comment: yes, tensorflow indeed reset Ld_LIBRARY_PATH, in its parent cuda image, it shows below:    

ENV PATH /usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:${PATH}
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64

Comment: In OpenDCOS, before mesos-agent startup, it set its executor's environment variable  LD_LIBRARY_PATH to "/opt/mesosphere/lib", so that it can locate necessary so files, But for some GPU applicagtions, such as CUDA image,  LD_LIBRARY_PATH is reset to "/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64" in its Dockerfile,  it will result an error during start GPU application: 
`mesos-containerizer: error while loading shared libraries: libmesos-1.0.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` 
   Anyone knows how OpenDCOS handle this problem ?

Comment: Try setting `MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY` to location of libmesos.so in docker container.